# Different 3D models depending on the qr code (Android)

Tags: android, qr-code, augmented-reality

I want to do an application on Android that reads a QR Code and depending on a string coded in it, does some calculations and renders a 3D arrow on top of the QR, and then to another QR Code and so on. I've read about many libraries (OpenCV, ARToolkit, NyARToolkit, AndAR...).

Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6MiJKgtbug), but with other models obviously.

I don't know where to start or any example I can use as help. Can anyone help me out finding the way forward?

Thanks.

P.D: Sorry about my english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AR on QR][1] displays 3D models above the QR Code and the model is selected based on the QR Code content.

Documentation & source code: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~cggc/Graphics-Geometric-Computing/Projects/pastProjects2013.html